# What are the best questions that could be turned into science fair projects?

Tags: discussion

I just came across this post: [Cooling a cup of coffee with help of a spoon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/cooling-a-cup-of-coffee-with-help-of-a-spoon) and think it would make a great science fair project for elementary and middle school students.  Are there other physics stackexchange questions that would serve a similar purpose?

(also, I think this fits under meta since it is discussing questions but not physics directly, but I admit I don't know if it is really appropriate)

Comment: It seems fine to ask here. It probably wouldn't go on the main site though. (Then again one _could_ perhaps make an argument that this is similar to the book recommendation question)